# How to make typography on image

Tags: android

**I want to make application like this  in android . I had made applications using Canvas but how to make application like this ?**

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=photo.text.typography

Answer (score 1):

Thats not very specific.
You do exactly that just by using a canvas.

The Processing is done in the background, and then they just display the image on the canvas.
And this app looks like they are just overlaying the original image with a preset alpha image. Not even really processing much.

Comment: Thanks..but they are using different fonts and their different size that are changed by user ...how to change these on actual image....and if i had to draw text on canvas it does not give that feel  of overlaying....

Comment: im pretty sure they are generating a image with some algorithm that fills the whole image with different sizes of text and different opacity. and then overlaying that produced image over the original. You dont use the normal text element you probably just draw text on a bitmap.

Comment: maybe something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHEQuoIKgNE&index=62&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZiZxtDDRCi6uhfTH4FilpH could lead you the way.. this would be a similar approach. He is using circles to redraw a text, maybe you can adapt it to get something you want out of it. If you go further in the playlist, he will do even more stuff with mosaic etc.